# Extract string before underscore in python string

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in python that looks something like: [AAA_X, BBB_X, CCC_X].

How can I efficiently extract the part of the string before the underscore?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? what errors did you bump into, what didn't work as you expected?

Comment: Is the underscore always after the 3rd string? Does `split` not help?

Comment: What if there is more than one underscore in a string - e.g., AAA_BBB_X What should the output be in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions can remove a suffix including the underscore from a string. Using regular expressions you can match on exactly what you want to operate on.

```python
import re
for s in ["AAA_X", "BBB_X", "CCC_X"]:
  print(s, ">>", re.sub(r"_.*", "", s))
```

**Output:**

```
AAA_X >> AAA
BBB_X >> BBB
CCC_X >> CCC
```

If want to output the prefix only when an underscore character is present in a string then can use the `re.match()` function. If no match such as input string "DDD" then the target string does not have a prefix followed by an underscore and will not be printed.

```python
import re
for s in ["AAA_X", "BBB_X", "CCC_X", "DDD"]:
  if m := re.match(r"(\w+)_", s):
     print(s, ">>", m.group(1))
```

The above code has identical output as the first code example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the *re* module for something so trivial. How about:

```
_list = ['AAA_X', 'BBB_X', 'CCC_X']

print(*(f'{e} >> {e.split("_")[0]}' for e in _list), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
AAA_X >> AAA
BBB_X >> BBB
CCC_X >> CCC
```